# Matplotlib Histogram has weird gaps in the data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have the following dataframe that consists of 50 rows where each row is a year and month formatted as datetime64[ns], with an Order_ct that is a count of number of orders that month formatted as int64, and two other fields.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data =\
{0: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2019-02-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 234,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': np.nan,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': np.nan},
 1: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2019-03-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 392,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': np.nan,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': np.nan},
 2: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2019-04-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 379,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': np.nan,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': np.nan},
 3: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2019-05-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 356,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': np.nan,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': np.nan},
 4: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2019-06-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 363,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': np.nan,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': np.nan},
 5: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2019-07-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 464,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': np.nan,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': np.nan},
 6: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2019-08-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 355,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': np.nan,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': np.nan},
 7: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2019-09-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 458,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': np.nan,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': np.nan},
 8: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2019-10-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 379,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': np.nan,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': np.nan},
 9: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2019-11-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 379,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': np.nan,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': np.nan},
 10: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2019-12-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 381,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': np.nan,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': np.nan},
 11: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 399,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': np.nan,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': np.nan},
 12: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2020-02-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 345,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 234.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': 47.43589743589743},
 13: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2020-03-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 306,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 392.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': -21.93877551020408},
 14: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2020-04-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 208,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 379.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': -45.11873350923483},
 15: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2020-05-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 275,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 356.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': -22.752808988764045},
 16: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2020-06-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 408,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 363.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': 12.396694214876034},
 17: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2020-07-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 428,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 464.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': -7.758620689655173},
 18: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2020-08-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 377,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 355.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': 6.197183098591549},
 19: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2020-09-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 431,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 458.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': -5.895196506550218},
 20: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2020-10-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 372,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 379.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': -1.8469656992084433},
 21: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2020-11-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 285,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 379.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': -24.80211081794195},
 22: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2020-12-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 341,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 381.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': -10.498687664041995},
 23: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 383,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 399.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': -4.010025062656641},
 24: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2021-02-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 407,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 345.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': 17.971014492753625},
 25: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2021-03-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 409,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 306.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': 33.66013071895425},
 26: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2021-04-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 366,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 208.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': 75.96153846153845},
 27: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2021-05-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 396,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 275.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': 44.0},
 28: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2021-06-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 365,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 408.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': -10.53921568627451},
 29: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2021-07-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 409,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 428.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': -4.439252336448598},
 30: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2021-08-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 353,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 377.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': -6.36604774535809},
 31: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2021-09-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 364,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 431.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': -15.54524361948956},
 32: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 322,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 372.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': -13.440860215053762},
 33: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2021-11-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 316,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 285.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': 10.87719298245614},
 34: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2021-12-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 328,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 341.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': -3.812316715542522},
 35: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 306,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 383.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': -20.10443864229765},
 36: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2022-02-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 283,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 407.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': -30.46683046683047},
 37: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2022-03-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 246,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 409.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': -39.85330073349633},
 38: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2022-04-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 302,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 366.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': -17.48633879781421},
 39: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2022-05-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 333,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 396.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': -15.909090909090908},
 40: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2022-06-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 293,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 365.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': -19.726027397260275},
 41: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2022-07-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 300,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 409.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': -26.65036674816626},
 42: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2022-08-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 354,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 353.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': 0.28328611898017},
 43: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2022-09-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 394,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 364.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': 8.241758241758241},
 44: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2022-10-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 389,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 322.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': 20.80745341614907},
 45: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2022-11-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 371,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 316.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': 17.405063291139243},
 46: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2022-12-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 333,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 328.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': 1.524390243902439},
 47: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 338,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 306.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': 10.457516339869281},
 48: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2023-02-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 354,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 283.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': 25.08833922261484},
 49: {'year_month': pd.Timestamp('2023-03-01 00:00:00'),
  'Order_ct': 379,
  'Order_ct_Prior_Year': 246.0,
  'Order_Perc_Chng': 54.0650406504065}}

df_test = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
```

I tried creating a histogram with the following code but I am getting some weird gaps in the bars and the values don't appear to be matching the bars. For example the first bar is above 600 but should be 234 matching the Order_ct for '2019-02-01'.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))

# Set background color of figure
fig.patch.set_facecolor('#fffcf2')
ax1.set_facecolor('#fffcf2')

# Create histogram on first axis
ax1.hist(df_test['year_month'], bins=50, weights=df_test['Order_ct'], color='#3d91e6', alpha=0.7)

# Set labels and title for first y-axis
ax1.set_xlabel('Order Month')
ax1.set_ylabel('Order Count')

# Set x-axis ticks to be the unique values in the 'year_month' column
ax1.set_xticks(df_test['year_month'].unique())

# Rotate x-axis tick labels by 45 degrees
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

# Show plot
plt.show()
```

[image: Example of the output]

Comment: This is a bar chart, not a histogram. `df_test.plot.bar(x='year_month', y='Order_ct', ax=ax1, width=1)` should get you most of the way there.

Comment: `df_test.year_month = df_test.year_month.dt.date` and then `ax = df_test.plot(kind='bar', x='year_month', y='Order_ct', ec='k', figsize=(12,6), xlabel='Order Date', ylabel='Order Count', legend=False)` produces this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuCPT.png).